# Tomcat and JDBC

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jndi, classcastexception

I am trying to configure the following on Tomcat.

```
Resource auth="Container" name="jdbc/yourDataSourceName"
         driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
         factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
         type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" 
         connectionCacheProperties="{}"
         connectionCachingEnabled="true"
         user="foo" 
         password="bar" 
         url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@foo.bar.com:1521:foobar"
```

When I put the following in my app `META-INF/context.xml` file, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
```

When I move this to `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml`, it works fine. It is not letting me configure specific to the app. Any ideas?

I have ojdbc6.jar in `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` as well as in `WEB-INF/lib` of my application  folder. Please advise. Am I missing something? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

You can try not to use specific Oracle classes such as "OracleDataSourceFactory" in your datasource configuration. It seems that Oracle Conn.pool is not compatible with DBCP.
Define driverClass only.

You can try something like this:

```
<Resource
name="jdbc/yourDataSourceName" auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@foo.bar.com:1521:foobar"
user="foo" 
password="bar"
maxActive="5" maxIdle="1" maxWait="-1"/>
```

Hope it will help